# node.js - PM2 log uncaught exceptions to third-party service (as Logentries)

Tags: javascript, node.js, uncaught-exception, pm2, logentries

I'm using pm2 (https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) in my node.js project. Also I'm sending logs of errors of the app in Logentries (https://logentries.com).

I wonder is it possible to log uncaught exceptions from the app (when something fails badly and pm2 restarts the app for example)? I know that using `process.on('uncaughtException')` is bad practice so would like to hear some suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where did you read that `process.on('uncaughtException')` is a bad practice?

As long as you exit the process after logging the exception I don't see what's bad, here is an example:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
    console.error('Ouch, an unhandled exception');
    //I like using new Error() for my errors (1)
    console.error(e instanceof Error ? e.message : e);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

(1): [Javascript Error reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Error)

**Edit**
pm2-interface is now deprecated, use `require('pm2')` instead. You will be able to do exactly the same as below by using [bus system events](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/doc/PROGRAMMATIC.md#bus-system---event-monitoring).

---

An alternative with pm2 is to use [pm2-interface](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2-interface/#notifications) and listening to the `process:exit` or `process:exception` events:

```
var ipm2 = require('pm2-interface')();

ipm2.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Connected to pm2');

  ipm2.bus.on('process:exception', function(data){
    console.log(data.pm2_env.name + 'had an exception');
  });
});
```

This is really usefull when managing more than one process through a monitoring process.

You might want to check the blog post on [how to build a custom pm2 logger](https://keymetrics.io/2014/07/10/pm2-interface-1-build-your-own-logger/). It can give you some ideas about monitoring processes through `pm2-interface`.

Comment: From the npm docs: `'uncaughtException' is a crude mechanism for exception handling intended to be used only as a last resort` https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_warning_using_uncaughtexception_correctly

Comment: It is not a good practice for production process to catch and resolve exceptions. However if you want to catch errors while remotely monitoring/debugging, it is useful

Comment: Your link "bus system events" is broken